# Firebase Admin .SDK request permission

Tags: c#, .net, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-admin-sdk

I am using Firebase Admin SDK .NET. 
How can I prompt the request permission popup from C# code? 
Calling FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance does nothing.

Prompt can be done only with the following javascript code?

```
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.requestPermission()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Have permission");
                    return messaging.getToken();
                })
                .then(function (token) {
                    console.log(token);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("Error occured");
                });
```